# How to sort the admin area of a WordPress custom post type by a custom field

Tags: custom-post-types

When editing one of my custom post types I want to be able to list all entries by a custom field instead of the date they are published (which, for a custom post type probably isn't relevant). I got a lead from the comments of a blog post about custom post types and the author said it was possible and that he even made it so you could click on the column names for a custom sort. He mentioned the [`posts_orderby`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) function which I noted in my own comments but now I can find the blog post anymore. Any suggestions? I saw one solution that used

```
add_action('wp', 'check_page');
```

And the `check_page` function used [`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) to change the query but I'm pretty sure it would only work in the theme files, not in the admin area.

Comment: Here another useful answer, to sort posts by ....<br/>
**http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66455/how-to-change-order-of-posts-in-admin**

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As you can probably imagine by the lack of answers provided, the solution is not exactly trivial. What I've done is create a somewhat self-contained example that assumes a custom post type of "`movie`" and custom field key of "*Genre*".

***Disclaimer***: this works with WP3.0 but I can't be sure it will work with earlier versions.

You basically need to hook two (2) hooks to make it work and another two (2) to make it obvious and useful.

The first hook is '`restrict_manage_posts`' which lets you emit an HTML `<select>` in the area above the list of posts where the "*Bulk Actions*" and "*Show Dates*" filters. The code provided will generate the "*Sort by:*" functionality as seen in this screen snippet:

[image: How to Create Sort By functionality for a Custom Post Type in the WordPress Admin]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20100811-210313.png))</sub>

The code uses direct SQL because there is not a WordPress API function to provide the list of all meta_keys for a post types (sounds like a future [trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org) ticket to me...)  Anyway, here's the code. Note that it grabs the post type from `$_GET` and validates to make sure it is both a valid post type `post_type_exists()` as well as being a `movie` post type (those two checks are overkill but I did it to show you how if you don't want to hard-code the post type.) Lastly I use the `sortby` URL parameter as it doesn't conflict with anything else in WordPress:

```
add_action('restrict_manage_posts','restrict_manage_movie_sort_by_genre');
function restrict_manage_movie_sort_by_genre() {
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
        if (post_type_exists($post_type) && $post_type=='movie') {
            global $wpdb;
            $sql=<<<SQL
SELECT pm.meta_key FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID=pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_type='movie' AND pm.meta_key='Genre'
GROUP BY pm.meta_key
ORDER BY pm.meta_key
SQL;
            $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
            $html = array();
            $html[] = "<select id=\"sortby\" name=\"sortby\">";
            $html[] = "<option value=\"None\">No Sort</option>";
            $this_sort = $_GET['sortby'];
            foreach($results as $meta_key) {
                $default = ($this_sort==$meta_key->meta_key ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
                $value = esc_attr($meta_key->meta_key);
                $html[] = "<option value=\"{$meta_key->meta_key}\"$default>{$value}</option>";
            }
            $html[] = "</select>";
            echo "Sort by: " . implode("\n",$html);
        }
    }
}
```

The second required step is to use the `parse_query` hook that is called after WordPress decides one what query is should run but before it runs the query. Here we get to set values of `orderby` and `meta_key` in the query's `query_var` array which are [documented in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Orderby_Parameters) in the `orderby` parameter for `query_posts()`. We test to make sure that:

1. We are in the admin (`is_admin()`),
2. We are on the page that lists posts in the admin (`$pagenow=='edit.php'`),
3. The page has been called with a `post_type` URL parameter equal to `movie`, and
4. The page has also been called with a `sortby` URL parameter and that it wasn't passed a value of '*None*'

If all those tests pass we then set the `query_vars` (as documented [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Orderby_Parameters)) to `meta_value` and our `sortby` value for '*Genre*':

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'sort_movie_by_meta_value' );
function sort_movie_by_meta_value($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    if (is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' &&
        isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type']=='movie' && 
        isset($_GET['sortby'])  && $_GET['sortby'] !='None')  {
        $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = $_GET['sortby'];
    }
}
```

And that's all you need to do; no "`posts_order`" or "`wp`" hooks required!  Of course you actually do need to do more; you need to add some columns on your page that lists the posts so you can actually see the values that it is sorting by otherwise the users will get mucho confused.  So add a `manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns` hook, in this case `manage_movie_posts_columns`. This hook gets passed the default array of columns and for simplicity I just replaced it with two standard columns; a checkbox (`cb`) and a post name (`title`). (You can inspect `posts_columns` with a `print_r()` to see what else is available by default.)

I decided to add a "*Sorted By:*" for when there is a `sortby` URL parameter and when it is not `None`:

```
add_action('manage_movie_posts_columns', 'manage_movie_posts_columns');
function manage_movie_posts_columns($posts_columns) {
    $posts_columns = array(
        'cb' => $posts_columns['cb'],
        'title' => 'Movie Name',
        );
    if (isset($_GET['sortby']) && $_GET['sortby'] !='None') 
        $posts_columns['meta_value'] = 'Sorted By';

    return $posts_columns;
}
```

Finally we use the `manage_pages_custom_column` hook to actually display the value when there is a post of the appropriate post type and with the probably redundant test for `is_admin()` and `$pagenow=='edit.php'`. When there is a `sortby` URL parameter we extract the custom field value that is being sorted by an display it in our list.  Here's what it looks like (remember, this is test data so no comments from the peanut gallery on the movie classifications! :):

[image: Custom Columns added for a Custom Post Type in the WordPress Admin]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20100811-210929.png))</sub>

And here is the code:

```
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column', 'manage_movie_pages_custom_column',10,2);
function manage_movie_pages_custom_column($column_name,$post_id) {
    global $pagenow;
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if ($post->post_type=='movie' && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php')  {
        switch ($column_name) {
            case 'meta_value':
                if (isset($_GET['sortby']) && $_GET['sortby'] !='None') {
                    echo get_post_meta($post_id,$_GET['sortby'],true);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this only picks up the first "*Genre*" for a `movie`, i.e. the first meta_value in the case of multiple values for a given key.  But then again I'm not sure how it would work otherwise!

And for those unfamiliar with where to put this code you can put it in a plugin or more likely for the newbie in the `functions.php` file in your current theme.

How this helps.

Comment: +1, just for the effort. But it would be even better [if the circles were hand-drawn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) :-)

Comment: Any idea how to remove the SHOW ALL DATES filter completely so that only my custom filters are showing for a given post type?

Comment: @RailsTweeter Use the technique I showed here where the two hooks that bracket the HTML generation are `'months_dropdown_results'` and `'restrict_manage_posts'`.
P.S. Upvotes are always appreciated. :)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel , now that there is a WP API, will this update your code somewhat?

Comment: @samjco Not sure. I unfortunately don't have the time to revise this at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

As of WordPress 3.1 (I'm using the beta) columns can now be sortable via their titles.

The following post details how implement them.

http://scribu.net/wordpress/custom-sortable-columns.html

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple solution:

```
/* --------Sortable Events on Dashboard - show start date, time, venue--------- */

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Custom Columns
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function my_*YOUR POST TYPE*_columns($columns)
{
    $columns = array(
        'cb'        => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title'     => 'Title',
        'your_custom_field'     => 'Custom Field Name',          
        'date'      =>  'Date',
    );
    return $columns;
}

function my_custom_columns($column)
{
    global $post;
    if($column == 'your_custom_field')
    {
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_custom_field', true);)
        {
            echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_custom_field', true);
        }
    }

}

add_action("manage_posts_custom_column", "my_custom_columns");
add_filter("manage_edit-*YOUR POST TYPE*_columns", "my_events_columns");

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sortable Columns
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function my_column_register_sortable( $columns )
{
    $columns['your_custom_field'] = 'your_custom_field';
    return $columns;
}

add_filter("manage_edit-*YOUR POST TYPE*_sortable_columns", "my_column_register_sortable" );
```

Just replace ***YOUR POST TYPE*** and **'your_custom_field'**