# Best way to manage a lot of pages in Wp Admin

Tags: plugins, pages, wp-admin

There is already a thread for this from 6 years ago here [How can we make managing lots of pages in WordPress Admin better?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/420/how-can-we-make-managing-lots-of-pages-in-wordpress-admin-better) but I can't believe I can't find something useful today. Most of these plugins are either out of service or are pretty meh in their functionality for 2016.

What do you guys use to organize a lot of page? Particuarly I am doing PPC landing campaign and would like to have a folder with a few dozen pages with minor variations on them.

Thank you!

Comment: To reopen this question, you will have to rephrase it. As it stands it's opinionated and therefore open ended. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This has been a reoccurring issue in WordPress. See these old trac links that are 9, 7 and 6 years-old respectively: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/3614, https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5303, https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14579

The challenge is that WordPress was built primarily for chronological posts since it began as a blogging tool. Page management was always secondary. WordPress still lacks an elegant solution for large-scale (>100) page management/content management when working with large amounts of non-chronological/hierarchical content like pages. The current list-based screens require paging through lists of data and make it difficult to see the hierarchy of content when the amount of content exceeds the upper limit of the page size (which defaults 20, max of 999). Other content management systems like Drupal and Umbraco use a content tree-based approach which makes managing large amounts of hierarchical content easier from a user experience perspective.

Until this limitation is addressed in the core WordPress admin area, you'll need to resort to outside solutions/plugins.

This best plugin I've found to manage a large number of pages is this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cms-tree-page-view/. It provides an ajax-driven, hierarchical tree view menu under the Pages menu in the WordPress admin area that provides a much better user experience and performance when working with a large number of pages (>100). There are other plugins as well, but this is one has 90,000+ active installs, an average rating of 4.9 starts with over 250 total ratings and is being actively maintained. It loads the top-level pages first and only loads child pages/content when you click to expand a node. It can be used with the pages post type or other hierarchical custom post types.

I have a site where we have nearly twenty thousand pages (with a lot of hierarchy) and this is the only way to deal with them. The built-in Pages menu is useless and often doesn't even load when you get a high number of pages like that.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer does not solve this question without the outside source link, which is something appreciated on all network sites. If you have a suggestion that involves code, can show measured performance stacks, etc. that adds in depth knowledge, then your answer deserves an upvote. Currently it is something that could have been a comment – for which I added a downvote. Maybe you want to invest more time in the answer and file an [edit]?

Comment: My comment answers the question as it was asked. If you don't like the way it was asked, then ask the questioner to rephrase (which I see that you did) but don't penalize a legitimate answer to the question he asked in the first place which was "What do you guys use to organize a lot of pages?". I get the open ended nature of his question, but part of the beauty of WordPress is the extensibility of the platform and vast plugin repository which helps you not reinvent the wheel (and need to write code) each time you encounter a problem. Next time I'll leave it as a comment.

Comment: Please, Andy: Take a trip to the [help] and take a look at the [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) page and the topic _Provide Context for links_. Thanks.

Comment: I hear ya kaiser. However, the same information and context I provided was accepted as an answer on this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/420/how-can-we-make-managing-lots-of-pages-in-wordpress-admin-better

I'll revise and provide additional context.

Comment: Different time, different- community selected- rules. The other answer is no answer and I will discuss that. Thanks for the heads up an your approach on this.

Comment: See revised. Let me know if you have any other suggested edits. Tried to remain as objective in my answer as possible.

Comment: That's a good answer now. While I would prefer to have a code–, or "at least" a concept answer – if we would be an agency – this is more than good enough: Explains the back story, offers a solution, shows the limitations. Thanks for the edit!