# Adding Fields to the Category, Tag and Custom Taxonomy Edit Screen in the WordPress Admin?

Tags: wp-admin, custom-field, categories, taxonomy, tags

The question is "***How do I add one or more fields to the Category, Tag and Custom Taxonomy Edit Screen in the WordPress Admin?***" This question was [asked on the wp-hackers list](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-August/033671.html) August 1st 2010 and [I offered a solution](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-August/033673.html) later that day. The [original asker discussed the issue again](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-August/034195.html) today (Aug 21) which reminded me of the solution. Since it could be a common need I decided to post the solution including code up here for others to find in the future.

Comment: Hi mike, I think it would be better if you post the code in answer box. That way, we have backup here, in case github down.

Comment: @silent: Hey, I'm working on it. :) I'm halfway done, but I've hit a wall and need to sleep. Here's what it'll look (something) like when I'm done: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/578/#582

Comment: Any more developments on this one? I'm actually kind of interested... :D

Comment: Hey *@John P Bloch*: My clients have pinned me down and just haven't had time. Hopefully soon...

Comment: @John P Bloch I actually tried it and it works great, I needed to 'group' certain categories without a parent category.

Comment: @Mike: Can we give this some traction? I don't understand the question fully, so you can probably give some example?

Comment: @hakre - And a happy holidays to you too! ;)  *(It's really easy for me to loose trac of things I meant to do here on WA because their system doesn't give an easy way to keep track of them. I would do now but I have an Xmas dinner to attend right now so it will have to be later.)*

Comment: See my answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29322/add-custom-taxonomy-fields-when-creating-a-new-taxonomy/41483#41483

Answer (score 24):

I added new field 'picture' (input type file) to category with help of these

```
add_action('category_edit_form_fields','category_edit_form_fields');
add_action('category_edit_form', 'category_edit_form');
add_action('category_add_form_fields','category_edit_form_fields');
add_action('category_add_form','category_edit_form');


function category_edit_form() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#edittag').attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" ).attr( "encoding", "multipart/form-data" );
        });
</script>
<?php 
}

function category_edit_form_fields () {
?>
    <tr class="form-field">
            <th valign="top" scope="row">
                <label for="catpic"><?php _e('Picture of the category', ''); ?></label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="file" id="catpic" name="catpic"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
    }
```

You are free to use any taxonomy, just replace `category` to your taxonomy name

Comment: this is excellent but could you please explain (or provide an example possibly) how one would correctly integrate this customization if you want to add this to a custom taxonomy - for example "people"

Comment: Update - Although I have copied your exact code above to test this the file does not seem to be saved or at least it is not showing up. Could you explain where its saving the file, maybe the permissions of that folder need to be edited (or even better, could you possibly describe how one would go about modifying the location of the folder where its saved?). When I select a file and then try to save a term its saving everything except for the file and thus does not show me the image uploaded.

Answer (score 10):

Also, if you want to add that field into the custom taxonomy form you just substitute category with the custom taxonomy name in the `add_action` function.

**Example:**

```
add_action('{custom_taxonomy}_edit_form_fields','category_edit_form_fields');
add_action('{custom_taxonomy}_edit_form', 'category_edit_form');
add_action('{custom_taxonomy}_add_form_fields','category_edit_form_fields');
add_action('{custom_taxonomy}_add_form','category_edit_form');
```

Answer (score 4):

I have Added the  add image and Remove image extra filed into custom taxonomy which name is insurance.

```
/**
 * Plugin class
 **/
if ( ! class_exists( 'CT_TAX_META' ) ) {

class CT_TAX_META {

  public function __construct() {
    //
  }

 /*
  * Initialize the class and start calling our hooks and filters
  * @since 1.0.0
 */
 public function init() {
   add_action( 'insurance_add_form_fields', array ( $this, 'add_category_image' ), 10, 2 );
   add_action( 'created_insurance', array ( $this, 'save_category_image' ), 10, 2 );
   add_action( 'insurance_edit_form_fields', array ( $this, 'update_category_image' ), 10, 2 );
   add_action( 'edited_insurance', array ( $this, 'updated_category_image' ), 10, 2 );
   add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'load_media' ) );
   add_action( 'admin_footer', array ( $this, 'add_script' ) );
 }

public function load_media() {
 wp_enqueue_media();
}

 /*
  * Add a form field in the new category page
  * @since 1.0.0
 */
 public function add_category_image ( $taxonomy ) { ?>
   <div class="form-field term-group">
     <label for="category-image-id"><?php _e('Image', 'hero-theme'); ?></label>
     <input type="hidden" id="category-image-id" name="category-image-id" class="custom_media_url" value="">
     <div id="category-image-wrapper"></div>
     <p>
       <input type="button" class="button button-secondary ct_tax_media_button" id="ct_tax_media_button" name="ct_tax_media_button" value="<?php _e( 'Add Image', 'hero-theme' ); ?>" />
       <input type="button" class="button button-secondary ct_tax_media_remove" id="ct_tax_media_remove" name="ct_tax_media_remove" value="<?php _e( 'Remove Image', 'hero-theme' ); ?>" />
    </p>
   </div>
 <?php
 }

 /*
  * Save the form field
  * @since 1.0.0
 */
 public function save_category_image ( $term_id, $tt_id ) {
   if( isset( $_POST['category-image-id'] ) && '' !== $_POST['category-image-id'] ){
     $image = $_POST['category-image-id'];
     add_term_meta( $term_id, 'category-image-id', $image, true );
   }
 }

 /*
  * Edit the form field
  * @since 1.0.0
 */
 public function update_category_image ( $term, $taxonomy ) { ?>
   <tr class="form-field term-group-wrap">
     <th scope="row">
       <label for="category-image-id"><?php _e( 'Image', 'hero-theme' ); ?></label>
     </th>
     <td>
       <?php $image_id = get_term_meta ( $term -> term_id, 'category-image-id', true ); ?>
       <input type="hidden" id="category-image-id" name="category-image-id" value="<?php echo $image_id; ?>">
       <div id="category-image-wrapper">
         <?php if ( $image_id ) { ?>
           <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image ( $image_id, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
         <?php } ?>
       </div>
       <p>
         <input type="button" class="button button-secondary ct_tax_media_button" id="ct_tax_media_button" name="ct_tax_media_button" value="<?php _e( 'Add Image', 'hero-theme' ); ?>" />
         <input type="button" class="button button-secondary ct_tax_media_remove" id="ct_tax_media_remove" name="ct_tax_media_remove" value="<?php _e( 'Remove Image', 'hero-theme' ); ?>" />
       </p>
     </td>
   </tr>
 <?php
 }

/*
 * Update the form field value
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
 public function updated_category_image ( $term_id, $tt_id ) {
   if( isset( $_POST['category-image-id'] ) && '' !== $_POST['category-image-id'] ){
     $image = $_POST['category-image-id'];
     update_term_meta ( $term_id, 'category-image-id', $image );
   } else {
     update_term_meta ( $term_id, 'category-image-id', '' );
   }
 }

/*
 * Add script
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
 public function add_script() { ?>
   <script>
     jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
       function ct_media_upload(button_class) {
         var _custom_media = true,
         _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
         $('body').on('click', button_class, function(e) {
           var button_id = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
           var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
           var button = $(button_id);
           _custom_media = true;
           wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment){
             if ( _custom_media ) {
               $('#category-image-id').val(attachment.id);
               $('#category-image-wrapper').html('<img class="custom_media_image" src="" style="margin:0;padding:0;max-height:100px;float:none;" />');
               $('#category-image-wrapper .custom_media_image').attr('src',attachment.url).css('display','block');
             } else {
               return _orig_send_attachment.apply( button_id, [props, attachment] );
             }
            }
         wp.media.editor.open(button);
         return false;
       });
     }
     ct_media_upload('.ct_tax_media_button.button'); 
     $('body').on('click','.ct_tax_media_remove',function(){
       $('#category-image-id').val('');
       $('#category-image-wrapper').html('<img class="custom_media_image" src="" style="margin:0;padding:0;max-height:100px;float:none;" />');
     });
     // Thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281995/wordpress-create-category-ajax-response
     $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
       var queryStringArr = settings.data.split('&');
       if( $.inArray('action=add-tag', queryStringArr) !== -1 ){
         var xml = xhr.responseXML;
         $response = $(xml).find('term_id').text();
         if($response!=""){
           // Clear the thumb image
           $('#category-image-wrapper').html('');
         }
       }
     });
   });
 </script>
 <?php }

  }

$CT_TAX_META = new CT_TAX_META();
$CT_TAX_META -> init();

}
```

Note: If you wanted to add this field to a different taxonomy, e.g. for a custom post type, you’d need to replace the reference to category with a reference to your own taxonomy slug. For example, if you add created a genre taxonomy you would hook this function via

```
add_action( 'taxonomy_add_form_fields', array ( $this, 'add_category_image' ), 10, 2 ).
```

My taxonomy slug name is insurance.

add_action( 'insurance_add_form_fields', array ( $this, 'add_category_image' ), 10, 2 );

Use this code in your `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 3):

For those looking to hook into the tag form field, the hook is slightly different.

```
add_tag_form_fields
```

instead of tag_add_form_fields as you would expect

Answer (score 1):

I realize this was asked a while ago, but WordPress has changed a bit since so I decided to develop a small script that simplifies the process of adding custom fields to taxonomies, and optionally lets you add columns to the terms table for each field. The script is called [amarkal-taxonomy](https://github.com/amarkal/amarkal-taxonomy), and is part of the [Amarkal](https://github.com/amarkal) WordPress framework.

Using `amarkal-taxonomy`, adding a custom field simplifies to:

```
// Add a text field to the 'category' taxonomy 'add' & 'edit' forms:
amarkal_taxonomy_add_field('category', 'cat_icon', array(
    'type'        => 'text',
    'label'       => 'Icon',
    'description' => 'The category\'s icon',
    'table'       => array(
        'show'      => true,  // Add a column to the terms table
        'sortable'  => true   // Make that column sortable
    )
));

// Then you can retrieve the data using:
$icon = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'cat_icon', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your code in to your themes functions.php file - also if you want to add that field into the custom taxonomy form you just substitute category with the custom taxonomy name in the add_action function.
Example :
add_action('category_edit_form_fields','category_edit_form_fields');
will be
add_action('custom_taxonomy_name_form_fields','function_name_to_hook_on');

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Category Meta PLugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-meta/). Works on all custom taxonomy's, tags & categorys