# add an image field to wordpress category

Tags: categories, database

i am trying to add an image field to the wp_term table in the database, I'll call it icon.

I want that filed to contain a URL to an image that will be the thumb for the category. I have already added the field to the DB and I have also inserted it into the code in the admin panel :

```
<?php if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical($taxonomy) ) : ?>
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="icon"><?php _ex(' Icon', 'Taxonomy Icon'); ?></label></th>
    <td><input name="icon" id="icon" type="text" value="<?php if ( isset( $tag->icon ) ) echo esc_attr($tag->icon); ?>" size="40" />
    <p class="description"><?php _e('The &#8220;icon&#8221; is the URL to the category icon. if it is an uploaded image it will be http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/wp-content/uploads/{your_file.name}.'); ?></p></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; // is_taxonomy_hierarchical() ?>
```

the code shows the content from the database if it is preset but doesnt update it.

what/where do i need to add so that it will also update the DB icon field?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some trouble saving custom taxonomy fields, which I resolved in [this WPSE post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29322/add-custom-taxonomy-fields-when-creating-a-new-taxonomy). I was using the options table to save my data, but the same solutions may apply for you too. Firing callbacks attached to `create_{taxonomy}` and `edited_{taxonomy}` were part of the solution.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but i found a great little plugin that lets me add all kinds of metadata to my categories
[link](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-meta/installation/)

Comment: haha funny there solution is what i used, thanks for it :)

Comment: Cheers, glad you go it worked out.