# Editing the term_order field

Tags: php, database, wp-admin, admin, terms

Can I add the term_order field to the terms edit page? I need a text field, not a sorting plugin.

Thank.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211703/need-a-simple-but-complete-example-of-adding-metabox-to-taxonomy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it yourself. If someone needs:

```
// Adding a field to sort on the category edit page
add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'product_cat_edit_category', 5 );
function product_cat_edit_category( $term ) {

    $term_order = get_term( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' );

    ?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><label for="description">Сортировка</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="term_order" value="<?php echo $term_order->term_order; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php

}

// Update term_order value when saving taxonomy
add_action( 'edit_product_cat', 'product_cat_save', 10, 1 );
function product_cat_save( $term_id ) {

    global $wpdb;

    if ( isset( $_POST['term_order'] ) ) {

        $term_order = $_POST['term_order'];

        $wpdb->query('UPDATE '.$wpdb->prefix.'terms SET term_order='.$term_order.' WHERE term_id='.$term_id);

        wp_redirect( esc_url_raw( get_edit_term_link( $term_id, 'product_cat', 'product' ) ) );

    }
}    //end function product_cat_save
```

In add_action, where `edit_product_cat` and`product_cat_edit_form_fields` should be the name of your taxonomy instead of product_cat. in my case, these are the categories of woocommerce products.