# Creating a table in the admin-style?

Tags: plugin-development, admin

What is the recommended way of creating a page with a table, in the style of the tables showing posts or users in the admin area?

I am expanding [the Cache Images plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cache-images/), and it contains a table with domains and a number of images from that domain. So there is no equivalent existing table that I can build upon (in the first version of this question, I asked about a table with posts, but there I could (maybe) [expand the existing post table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/578/adding-a-taxonomy-filter-to-admin-list-for-a-custom-post-type/582#582)).

Should I just base myself on [the post overview page](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/edit-post-rows.php), and start with a `<table class="widefat">`, or are there better functions that handle this now? Do you know a clean, empty example of a table with paging that I could base my work on?

Comment: There is a new blog for the WordPress UI styleguide, you may find it helpful. http://dotorgstyleguide.wordpress.com/outline/

Comment: Note to self: scribu added [a new ajaxified table system in WP 3.1](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14579), with a base class `WP_List_Table`. This question can probably be updated with information on how to use it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is what I generally use:

```
<table class="widefat fixed" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>

            <th id="cb" class="manage-column column-cb check-column" scope="col"></th> // this column contains checkboxes
            <th id="columnname" class="manage-column column-columnname" scope="col"></th>
            <th id="columnname" class="manage-column column-columnname num" scope="col"></th> // "num" added because the column contains numbers

    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
    <tr>

            <th class="manage-column column-cb check-column" scope="col"></th>
            <th class="manage-column column-columnname" scope="col"></th>
            <th class="manage-column column-columnname num" scope="col"></th>

    </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="alternate">
            <th class="check-column" scope="row"></th>
            <td class="column-columnname"></td>
            <td class="column-columnname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="check-column" scope="row"></th>
            <td class="column-columnname"></td>
            <td class="column-columnname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alternate" valign="top"> // this row contains actions
            <th class="check-column" scope="row"></th>
            <td class="column-columnname">
                <div class="row-actions">
                    <span><a href="#">Action</a> |</span>
                    <span><a href="#">Action</a></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="column-columnname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top"> // this row contains actions
            <th class="check-column" scope="row"></th>
            <td class="column-columnname">
                <div class="row-actions">
                    <span><a href="#">Action</a> |</span>
                    <span><a href="#">Action</a></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="column-columnname"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: is it also to have automatic pagination inserted like this? (e.g. showing post 1-20)

Comment: @MichielStandaert No.

Comment: @MichielStandaert if you want a paginated result you can use [paginate_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

Comment: Thanks ! (But I still asking why they didn't use `:odd` for row instead of let us add a class each two rows ...)

Comment: There are obviously "better" solutions (like the other answers here), but for a quick, basic table, this is exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 32):

### Use the Core API, not only its CSS

Normally you just use an instance of the `WP_List_Table` class.

#### Guides:

- More about it in the Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table).
- Here's also a guide from [WP Engineer](http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/) - too much to copy it over.
- And another guide on [Smashing Magazine](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/03/native-admin-tables-wordpress/) online.

### Benefits?

YES!

You can add pagination, search boxes, actions and whatever magic you can imagine (and are able to code).

Comment: Small hint as link to see markup, classes for the admin interface, without only the goal to create tables: https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style

Comment: >This class's access is marked as private. That means it is not intended for use by plugin and theme developers as it is subject to change without warning in any future WordPress release. If you would still like to make use of the class, you should make a copy to use and distribute with your own project, or else use it at your own risk.

Comment: @AustinPray _A copy_ ? No, please do not do that. There are betas, RCs and other pre-releases of WP available. Just update your implementation/ extension. If you really have to go sideways, just write something better on your own. The core code isn't _that_ good.

Comment: @kaiser Don't shoot the messenger, those aren't my words. I was quoting from the WP Codex. Although signing yourself up for perpetual regression testing with every beta and RC doesn't sound much better than copying the class. I agree writing your own simple class is a better way forward.

Comment: @AustinPray No hard feelings :) Codex is written by people like you and me. In fact, you can go now and revert that statement and people will quote it.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of the guides are woefully out of date, as of Wordpress 5, which I found the hard way while breaking things (Also the Smashing Managzine one has glaring syntax errors - someone failed to master copy&paste). I haven't found an up to date alternative (the `custom-list-table-example` is only slightly better) and the Codex has a lot of things missing. I managed to write a simple implementation by looking at Wordpress itself, especially `class-wp-users-list-table.php` which is almost fully featured but simpler than other WP classes.

Comment: @Guss The answer is from 2012. You might want to add your own answer to offer a more up to date solution :)

Comment: @Kaiser - did that. See below :-)

Answer (score 13):

Use this example (written as a plugin) to create your admin tables:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-list-table-example/

It uses the built-in [WP_List_Table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) class.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. Also see this article in Smashing Magazine that articulates a similar approach: http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/03/native-admin-tables-wordpress/

Comment: This plugin is no longer maintained and does not work with Wordpress 5.

Answer (score 5):

Also you can use this small plugin for view the possibilities of the backend in WP: https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style

Answer (score 2):

For those looking to implement `WP_List_Table`, please note that all guides I found are woefully out of date and will either have write redundant code or actually ask you to do things that no longer work.

Here is a minimal example that works to some degree. It should be easy to understand without a "guide" and will get you started.

Includes:

- quick filters (views)
- search box
- row actions

Missing:

- page size configuration (I actually haven't seen a Wordpress page use this)
- bulk actions
- pulldown filters

```php
class My_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct([
            'singular' => 'employee',
            'plural' => 'employees',
        ]);
    }

    function get_columns() {
        return [
            'name'      => __('Name'),
            'employer' => __('Employer'),
            'rank'     => __('Rank'),
            'phone'    => __('Telephone'),
            'joined'   => __('Join Date'),
        ];
    }

    /* Optional - without it no column is sortable */
    public function get_sortable_columns() {
        return [
           // keys are "column_name" like above
           // values are "order" field names as per what your data model needs
            'name'     => 'name',
            'employer' => 'employer',
            'rank'     => 'rank',
            'joined'   => 'joined',
        ];
    }

    public function prepare_items() {
       // support the search box
        $search = @$_REQUEST['s'] ? wp_unslash(trim($_REQUEST['s']))) : '';
       // get number of records per page setting from option storage
        $per_page = $this->get_items_per_page('my_list_table_per_page');
       // fill data array with your model items. In my implementation these
       // are StdClass instances with various fields, but it can be anything
       // we'll see in a minute how.
        $this->items = get_model_items([
            'offset' => ($this->get_pagenum()-1)*$per_page,
            'count' => $per_page,
            'orderby' => @$_GET["orderby"] ?: 'id', // default order field, if not specified
            'order' => @$_GET["order"] ?: 'ASC', // default order direction
            'search' => $search, // pass search field if set
            'status' => @$_REQUEST['status'] // pass view filter, if set [see get_views()]
        );
        $this->set_pagination_args([
            "total_items" => get_model_item_count(),
            "per_page" => $per_page,
        ]);
       // `get_model_item_count` should be the total number of records after
       // filtering (views and search) but before paging. This may be hard/inefficient
       // to do with MySQL. If you want to put the results of `COUNT(*)` here,
       // no one will blame you.
    }

    public function column_default($item, $column_name) {
        // default column presentation
        // Most of my object fields are printable as is, so we have a generic
        // method to handle that.
        return $item->$column_name;
    }

    /* Optional, unless you have data that requires special formatting */
    public function column_joined($item) {
        // The 'joined' field is a DateTime object and can't be implicitly
       // converted to string by the built-in logic, so we'll need to do it
        return $item->joined->format("Y-m-d");
    }

   /* Optional - draw quick filters on top of the table */
    public function get_views() {
        $makelink = function($filter_val, $name) { // DRYing tool for view makers
            $filter_name = 'status';
            return '<a href="'
                . esc_url(add_query_arg($filter_name, $filter_val)) . '" ' .
                (@$_REQUEST[$filter_name]==$filter_val ? 
                    'class="current" aria-current="page"' : ''). ">" .
                $name . "</a>";
        };
        return [
            'all' => $makelink(false, __('All')),
            'green' => $makelink('green', __('Newbs')),
            'pros' => $makelink('pro', __('Experts')),
            'bofh' => $makelink('veteran', __('Crusty fellows')),
        ];
    }

    /* Optional: row actions */
    public function handle_row_actions($item, $column_name, $primary) {
        $out = parent::handle_row_actions($item, $column_name, $primary);
        if ($column_name === $primary)
            $out .= $this->row_actions([
                'edit' => sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                    add_query_arg('employee_id', $item->id, admin_url('admin.php?page=edit-employee')),
                    __("Edit")),
                'delete' => sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                    add_query_arg('employee_id', $item->id, admin_url('admin.php?page=delete-employee')),
                    __("Delete")),
            ]);
        return $out;
    }

}
```

Then the admin page function (for `add_menu_page`/`add_submenu_page`) may look like this:

```php
function drawAdminPage() {
    $my_list_table = new My_List_Table();
    $my_list_table->prepare_items();
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h1 class="wp-heading-inline"><?php _e('Admin Page Title')?></h1>
    <hr class="wp-header-end">
    <?php $my_list_table->views() ?>
    <form id="employee-filter" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['page']?>">
    <?php $my_list_table->search_box(__('Search'), 'employee') ?>
    <?php $my_list_table->display(); ?>
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: There goes your upvote.

Answer (score 2):

There are many good options here. But there isn't a quick'n'dirty one:

```html
<table class="widefat striped fixed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header1</th>
            <th>Header2</th>
            <th>Header3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Content1</td>
            <td>Content2</td>
            <td>Content3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Footer1</th>
            <th>Footer2</th>
            <th>Footer3</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Explanation**

- The `widefat`-class is used by the `common.css`, loaded in the admin, to make it look like a WP-table.
- The `striped`-class makes it striped (what a surprise).
- The `fixed`-class adds the CSS: `table-layout: fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider adding a filter to your custom post type list in the admin? The linked answer below shows how to do it with a taxonomy but you could easily use other criteria  in your `restrict_manage_posts` hook:

- [**Adding a Taxonomy Filter to Admin List for a Custom Post Type?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/578/adding-a-taxonomy-filter-to-admin-list-for-a-custom-post-type/582#582)

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: I apologize for the unclear question. In my first example it was a table of posts, and indeed, I could try to use the existing post table for that (even if I only want to show the post titles and then all custom columns?). But now I have edited my question with a concrete example: I have a table of domains, so there is no equivalent existing table that I can expand.

Comment: *@Jan*: Ah. Yes, I think you have found the truth, that there is not good encapsulated way to do this other than writing (duplicated) HTML. I've often had the same issue. Maybe create a ticket on trac asking for this enhancement and link the URL/ticket# here so we can support it.