# Add multiple taxonomy filters to edit.php that support search

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search

After reading through this fantastic tutorial by Mike Schinkel:

[Adding a Taxonomy Filter to Admin List for a Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/578/adding-a-taxonomy-filter-to-admin-list-for-a-custom-post-type)

I have discovered a few issues that I need to work out. Search does not seem to work properly with custom taxonomy filters applied. Also, if I output more than one custom taxonomy filter dropdown, what's the best way to prevent a user from specifying values for more than one of the dropdowns? I'm thinking I should just add a JavaScript function, but it might have to be a dynamically generated JavaScript function.

I really want to tackle the search issue first, though.

Any thoughts? Thanks for your help,
Dave Morris

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out by using this code:

```
function override_is_tax_on_post_search($query) {
        global $pagenow;
        $qv = &$query->query_vars;
        if ($pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset($qv['taxonomy']) && isset($qv['s'])) {
            $query->is_tax = true;
        }
    }
}
add_filter('parse_query','override_is_tax_on_post_search');
```

Comment: If that's based on Mike's code, it's missing the code that switches the term id for a slug(which is required for the filter to work, unless you render the dropdown differently).. **note:** there's an error in your code(extra curly brace).. Your fix however, does work... :)