# Help with issues on "Adding a Taxonomy Filter to Admin List for a Custom Post Type?"

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, filters

This question relates to a solution found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/578/adding-a-taxonomy-filter-to-admin-list-for-a-custom-post-type) from user somatic and mikeSchinkel

I am testing somatic's solution, and it loads and populates the dropdown with no issues, but When you click filter, it does not filter anything. I am on WP version 3.0.4.

My custom post type = "listings" my custom taxonomy = "Locations"

the code:

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'my_restrict_manage_posts' );
function my_restrict_manage_posts() {

    // only display these taxonomy filters on desired custom post_type listings
    global $typenow;
    if ($typenow == 'listings') {

        // create an array of taxonomy slugs you want to filter by - if you want to retrieve all taxonomies, could use get_taxonomies() to build the list
        $filters = array('Locations');

        foreach ($filters as $tax_slug) {
            // retrieve the taxonomy object
            $tax_obj = get_taxonomy($tax_slug);
            $tax_name = $tax_obj->labels->name;
            // retrieve array of term objects per taxonomy
            $terms = get_terms($tax_slug);

            // output html for taxonomy dropdown filter
            echo "<select name='$tax_slug' id='$tax_slug' class='postform'>";
            echo "<option value=''>Show All $tax_name</option>";
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                // output each select option line, check against the last $_GET to show the current option selected
                echo '<option value='. $term->slug, $_GET[$tax_slug] == $term->slug ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>' . $term->name .' (' . $term->count .')</option>';
            }
            echo "</select>";
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something in there to make the filter work? I am organizing my column's with the following code, not what was in step 3 and 4. (not sure if this is the issue?)

```
add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "listing_custom_columns");
add_filter("manage_edit-listings_columns", "listing_edit_columns");

function listing_edit_columns($columns){
  $columns = array(
    "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
    "title" => "Listing Name",
    "address" => "Address",
    "Locations" => "Location",
  );

  return $columns;
}
function listing_custom_columns($column){
  global $post;

  switch ($column) {
    case "address":
      $custom = get_post_custom();
      echo $custom["address_meta"][0];
      break;
    case "Locations":
      echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'Locations', '', ', ','');
      break;
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem like you. Don't know why mikeSchinkels code doesn't work anymore. But there are a new (WordPress 3.1) code for this, that works.

I found it here: https://gist.github.com/541505#gistcomment-28441 (in mikes comments)

I replaced mikes code from line 65 to 95, with this code. (check Mikes code on github) Other then that, follow his original structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the example you gave, the term that you put in the $filters array has to be lower case since it is a slug.  So 'Location' has to be 'location' or whatever the slug is for that taxonomy.

Comment: I tried putting 'locations' in instead of 'Locations' and it then wouldnt give me the list form the taxonomy. Thanks for the suggestion though.