# How to show the taxonomy assigned to a post in the table (where all the posts are displayed) of the custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

Right now I use the following code to create a custom post type and assign a taxonomy to it:

```
// === CUSTOM TAXONOMIES === //
add_action('init', 'my_custom_taxonomies', 0);

function my_custom_taxonomies() {
 register_taxonomy(
  'section',  // internal name = machine-readable taxonomy name
  'static_content',  // object type = post, page, link, or custom post-type
  array(
   'hierarchical' => true,
   'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Section' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Section' ),
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Section',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Section',
    'new_item' => 'New Section',
    'search_items' => 'Search Section',
    'not_found' => 'No Sections found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Sections found in trash',
    'all_items' => __( 'All Sections' ),
   ),
   'query_var' => true, // enable taxonomy-specific querying
   'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'section' ), // pretty permalinks for your taxonomy?
  )
 );
 wp_insert_term('Footer', 'section');
 wp_insert_term('Header', 'section');
 wp_insert_term('Front Page Intro', 'section');
 wp_insert_term('Front Page Content', 'section');
}

// === CUSTOM POST TYPES === //
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_post_types' );

function create_my_post_types() {
 register_post_type( 'static_content',
  array(
   'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Static Content' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Static Content' ),
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Static Content',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Static Content',
    'new_item' => 'New Static Content',
    'search_items' => 'Search Static Content',
    'not_found' => 'No Static Content found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Static Content found in trash',
   ),
   '_builtin' => false,
   'public' => true,
   'hierarchical' => false,
   'taxonomies' => array( 'section'),
   'supports' => array(
    'title',
    'editor',
    'excerpt'
   ),
   'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'static_content', 'with_front' => false )
  )
 );
}
```

When I click the menu of the custom post type (in this case "Static Content"), I see in the table/column (where all the posts are displayed) the following information: Title, Author and Date. I would like to show the taxonomy assigned to that post (in this case the "Section".)

How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with issues on "Adding a Taxonomy Filter to Admin List for a Custom Post Type?"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6381/help-with-issues-on-adding-a-taxonomy-filter-to-admin-list-for-a-custom-post-typ)

Comment: @t310s - I definitely don't want to appear contradictory but I feel like that other question was related but not identical. As such I'm going to help out @janoChen and answer it.

Comment: No problem, go for it.. :) ..and i've retracted my previous comment..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using my test site and some test code this is what I think you were looking for?

[image: Screenshot of WordPress Custom Post List in the Admin showing associated Taxonomies]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20110122-234130.png))</sub>

To achieve this you need to use two (2) hooks, one being specific to your post type: `'manage_static_content_posts_columns'` and `'manage_posts_custom_column'`.  In order to make it work I took your code and packaged it in a class, and also made it a plugin *(it doesn't have to be a plugin; you could just take the code and put in in your theme's `functions.php` file if you like.)*

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin name: Static Content
*/
if (!class_exists('YourSite_StaticContent')) {
  class YourSite_StaticContent {
    static function on_load() {
      add_action('init',array(__CLASS__,'init'));
      add_filter('manage_static_content_posts_columns',
          array(__CLASS__,'manage_static_content_posts_columns'));
      add_filter('manage_posts_custom_column', 
          array(__CLASS__,'manage_posts_custom_column'));
    }
    function manage_static_content_posts_columns($columns){
      $new = array();
      foreach($columns as $key => $title) {
        if ($key=='author') // Put the Sections column before the Author column
          $new['sections'] = 'Sections';
        $new[$key] = $title;
      }
      return $new;
    }
    static function manage_posts_custom_column($column){
      global $post;
      switch ($column) {
        case "sections":
          echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'section', '', ', ','');
          break;
      }
    }
    static function init() {
      register_post_type('static_content',array(
        'labels' => array(
          'name' => __( 'Static Content' ),
          'singular_name' => __( 'Static Content' ),
          'add_new_item' => 'Add New Static Content',
          'edit_item' => 'Edit Static Content',
          'new_item' => 'New Static Content',
          'search_items' => 'Search Static Content',
          'not_found' => 'No Static Content found',
          'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Static Content found in trash',
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'taxonomies' => array( 'section'),
        'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'static_content','with_front'=>false),
      ));
      register_taxonomy('section','static_content',array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
          'name' => __( 'Section' ),
          'singular_name' => __( 'Section' ),
          'add_new_item' => 'Add New Section',
          'edit_item' => 'Edit Section',
          'new_item' => 'New Section',
          'search_items' => 'Search Section',
          'not_found' => 'No Sections found',
          'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Sections found in trash',
          'all_items' => __( 'All Sections' ),
        ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'section' ),
        ));
      if (!get_option('yoursite-static-content-initialized')) {
        $terms = array(
          'Footer',
          'Header',
          'Front Page Intro',
          'Front Page Content',
          );
        foreach($terms as $term) {
          if (!get_term_by('name',$term,'section')) {
            wp_insert_term($term, 'section');
          }
        }
        update_option('yoursite-static-content-initialized',true);
      }
    }
  }
  YourSite_StaticContent::on_load();
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks. (By the way did you do something similar to this with your client?)

Comment: @janoChen - Thanks, and glad I could help.  Yes I did similar on mandslaw.com. It is pretty much (in my opinion) a standard "must have" for custom post types; each type has a set of data that is relevant to it and the "standard" list isn't that useful in many cases.