# Creating a drop-down and filter button for two custom taxonomies assigned to a custom post type

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters

I'm using the following code to create drop-down menu and filter button for two custom taxonomies assigned to a custom post type called Page Content (full previous code [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7492/how-to-show-the-taxonomy-assigned-to-a-post-in-the-table-where-all-the-posts-are)):

```
        function parse_query($query) {
            global $pagenow;
            $qv = &$query->query_vars;
            if ($pagenow=='edit.php' &&
                isset($qv['taxonomy']) && $qv['taxonomy']=='locations' &&
                isset($qv['term']) && is_numeric($qv['term'])) {
                    $term = get_term_by('id',$qv['term'],'locations');
                    $qv['term'] = $term->slug;
                }
            if ($pagenow=='edit.php' &&
                isset($qv['taxonomy']) && $qv['taxonomy']=='page_sections' &&
                isset($qv['term']) && is_numeric($qv['term'])) {
                    $term = get_term_by('id',$qv['term'],'page_sections');
                    $qv['term'] = $term->slug;
                }
        }
        // Add filter drop-down menu for the custom taxonomies
        function restrict_manage_posts() {
            global $typenow;
            global $wp_query;
            if ($typenow=='page_content') {
                $taxonomy = 'locations';
                $locations = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
                wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                    'show_option_all' =>  __("Show All {$locations->label}"),
                    'taxonomy'        =>  $taxonomy,
                    'name'            =>  $taxonomy,
                    'orderby'         =>  'name',
                    'selected'        =>  $wp_query->query['term'],
                    'hierarchical'    =>  true,
                    'depth'           =>  3,
                    'show_count'      =>  true,  // This will give a view
                    'hide_empty'      =>  true,   // This will give false positives, i.e. one's not empty related to the other terms. TODO: Fix that
                ));
            }
            if ($typenow=='page_content') {
                $taxonomy = 'page_sections';
                $page_sections = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
                wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                    'show_option_all' =>  __("Show All {$page_sections->label}"),
                    'taxonomy'        =>  $taxonomy,
                    'name'            =>  $taxonomy,
                    'orderby'         =>  'name',
                    'selected'        =>  $wp_query->query['term'],
                    'hierarchical'    =>  true,
                    'depth'           =>  3,
                    'show_count'      =>  true,  // This will give a view
                    'hide_empty'      =>  true,   // This will give false positives, i.e. one's not empty related to the other terms. TODO: Fix that
                ));
        }
    }
    YourSite_PageContent::on_load();
}
```

But I'm getting the following warning:

```
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, 
expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/alex/www/wpac/wp-content/themes
/prominent/functions/custom-post-types.php on line 181
```

This is line 181: `YourSite_PageContent::on_load();`

Comment: Missing closing brace on the final `if` condition.

Comment: Added as answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing brace on the final if condition. ;)