# Drop-down filter doesn't retrieve custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters

**Wordpress 3.0.4:**

[image]

**Wordpress 3.1 RC4:**

[image]

**functions.php (The last part is the one involved in filtering and displaying the drop-down menu):**

```
<?php

/**
 * Create the Page Content custom post type and the Page Section custom taxonomy
 */
add_action('init', 'my_init_method');

if (!class_exists('YourSite_PageContent')) {
    class YourSite_PageContent {
        static function on_load() {
            add_action('init',array(__CLASS__,'init'));
            add_filter('manage_page_content_posts_columns',
                array(__CLASS__,'manage_page_content_posts_columns'));
            add_filter('manage_posts_custom_column',
                array(__CLASS__,'manage_posts_custom_column'),10,2);
            add_action('restrict_manage_posts',
                array(__CLASS__,'restrict_manage_posts'));
            add_filter('parse_query',
                array(__CLASS__,'parse_query'));
        }
        // Register custom post types and custom taxonomies
        static function init() {
            register_post_type('page_content',array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Page Content' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Page Content' ),
                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Page Content',
                    'edit_item' => 'Edit Page Content',
                    'new_item' => 'New Page Content',
                    'search_items' => 'Search Page Content',
                    'not_found' => 'No Page Content found',
                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Page Content found in trash',
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'taxonomies' => array( 'page_sections'),
                'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
                'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'page_content','with_front'=>false),
            ));
            register_taxonomy('locations','page_content',array(
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Locations' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Page Section' ),
                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Page Section',
                    'edit_item' => 'Edit Page Section',
                    'new_item' => 'New Page Section',
                    'search_items' => 'Search Page Section',
                    'not_found' => 'No Page Sections found',
                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Page Sections found in trash',
                    'all_items' => __( 'All Page Sections' ),
                ),
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'locations' ),
            ));
            register_taxonomy('page_sections','page_content',array(
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Page Sections' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Page Section' ),
                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Page Section',
                    'edit_item' => 'Edit Page Section',
                    'new_item' => 'New Page Section',
                    'search_items' => 'Search Page Section',
                    'not_found' => 'No Page Sections found',
                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Page Sections found in trash',
                    'all_items' => __( 'All Page Sections' ),
                ),
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'page_sections' ),
            ));
            // Add initial terms
            if (!get_option('yoursite-page-content-initialized')) {
                $terms = array(
                    'Footer',
                    'Header',
                    'Front Page Intro',
                    'Front Page Content',
                );
                foreach($terms as $term) {
                    if (!get_term_by('name',$term,'page_sections')) {
                        wp_insert_term($term, 'page_sections');
                    }
                }
                update_option('yoursite-page-content-initialized',true);
            }
        }
        //Arrange the position of elements in the table
        function manage_page_content_posts_columns($columns) {
            $columns = array(
                'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
                'title' => 'Name',
                'locations_column' => 'Locations',
                'page_sections_column' => 'Page Sections',
                'author' => 'Author',
                'date' => 'Date',
            );
            return $columns;
        }
        function manage_posts_custom_column( $column,$post_id ) {
            global $typenow;
            if ($typenow=='page_content') {
                $locations_taxonomy = 'locations';
                $page_sections_taxonomy = 'page_sections';
                switch ($column) {
                case 'locations_column':
                    $locations_column = get_the_terms($post_id,$locations_taxonomy);
                    if (is_array($locations_column)) {
                        foreach($locations_column as $key => $locations) {
                            $edit_link = get_term_link($locations,$locations_taxonomy);
                            $locations_column[$key] = '<a href="'.$edit_link.'">' . $locations->name . '</a>';
                        }
                        echo implode(' | ',$locations_column);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'page_sections_column':
                    $page_sections_column = get_the_terms($post_id,$page_sections_taxonomy);
                    if (is_array($page_sections_column)) {
                        foreach($page_sections_column as $key => $page_sections) {
                            $edit_link = get_term_link($page_sections,$page_sections_taxonomy);
                            $page_sections_column[$key] = '<a href="'.$edit_link.'">' . $page_sections->name . '</a>';
                        }
                        echo implode(' | ',$page_sections_column);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        function parse_query($query) {
            global $pagenow;
            $qv = &$query->query_vars;
            if ($pagenow=='edit.php' &&
                isset($qv['taxonomy']) && $qv['taxonomy']=='page_sections' &&
                isset($qv['term']) && is_numeric($qv['term'])) {
                    $term = get_term_by('id',$qv['term'],'page_sections');
                    $qv['term'] = $term->slug;
                }
        }
        function restrict_manage_posts() {
            global $typenow;
            global $wp_query;
            if ($typenow=='page_content') {
                $taxonomy = 'page_sections';
                $page_sections = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
                wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                    'show_option_all' =>  __("Show All {$page_sections->label}"),
                    'taxonomy'        =>  $taxonomy,
                    'name'            =>  $taxonomy,
                    'orderby'         =>  'name',
                    'selected'        =>  $wp_query->query['term'],
                    'hierarchical'    =>  true,
                    'depth'           =>  3,
                    'show_count'      =>  true,  // This will give a view
                    'hide_empty'      =>  true,   // This will give false positives, i.e. one's not empty related to the other terms. TODO: Fix that
                ));
            }
        }
    }
    YourSite_PageContent::on_load();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

is it because you aren't returning a value to the parse_query filter?  or otherwise passing it by reference.

```
function parse_query(&$query) {  //added the reference &
            global $pagenow;
            $qv = &$query->query_vars;
            if ($pagenow=='edit.php' &&
                isset($qv['taxonomy']) && $qv['taxonomy']=='page_sections' &&
                isset($qv['term']) && is_numeric($qv['term']) &&$qv['term']>0) { //added check for greater than 0 as the default ALL is zero and that throws some warnings
                    $term = get_term_by('id',$qv['term'],'page_sections');
                    $qv['term'] = $term->slug;
                }
        }
```

other than that this looks very much like the code i just used this weekend found: [Adding a Taxonomy Filter to Admin List for a Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/578/6477#12856)