# restrict_manage_posts not working in 3.3.1

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin, query, dropdown

I have noticed my custom taxonomy filters no longer work in the 3.3.1 admin as per these methods:
[Adding a Taxonomy Filter to Admin List for a Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/578/adding-a-taxonomy-filter-to-admin-list-for-a-custom-post-type/42726#42726)

I also discovered that to filter a taxonomy the query string requires both the `&taxonomy=whatever` and `&term=something` to be passed. Anyone have any experience in this, and solutions to offer?

Here's some code from the question as an example:

```
add_action('restrict_manage_posts','restrict_listings_by_business');
function restrict_listings_by_business() {
    global $typenow;
    global $wp_query;
    if ($typenow=='listing') {
        $taxonomy = 'business';
        $business_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
        wp_dropdown_categories(array(
            'show_option_all' =>  __("Show All {$business_taxonomy->label}"),
            'taxonomy'        =>  $taxonomy,
            'name'            =>  'business',
            'orderby'         =>  'name',
            'selected'        =>  $wp_query->query['term'],
            'hierarchical'    =>  true,
            'depth'           =>  3,
            'show_count'      =>  true, // Show # listings in parens
            'hide_empty'      =>  true, // Don't show businesses w/o listings
        ));
    }
}
```

and

```
add_filter('parse_query','convert_business_id_to_taxonomy_term_in_query');
function convert_business_id_to_taxonomy_term_in_query($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    $qv = &$query->query_vars;
    if ($pagenow=='edit.php' &&
            isset($qv['taxonomy']) && $qv['taxonomy']=='business' &&
            isset($qv['term']) && is_numeric($qv['term'])) {
        $term = get_term_by('id',$qv['term'],'business');
        $qv['term'] = $term->slug;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have a CPT listing, with 'business' taxonomy? What do you mean by it doesn't work - the filter doesn't seem to apply (i.e. all posts still appear)?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was unclear. All post appear.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of things wrong with your code...

1. when filtering it is not `term` that gives the ID of the term, but `business` (in this case), since this is the name you've provided for the drop-down menu. Replace all instances of `term` with `business`
2. Taxonomy is not set when filtering. Remove this check from `parse_query` function.

The following worked for me (except I changed 'listing' to 'post')...

```
add_action('restrict_manage_posts','restrict_listings_by_business');
function restrict_listings_by_business() {
    global $typenow;
    global $wp_query;
    if ($typenow=='post') {
    $taxonomy = 'business';
    $term = isset($wp_query->query['business']) ? $wp_query->query['business'] :'';
    $business_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
        wp_dropdown_categories(array(
            'show_option_all' =>  __("Show All"),
            'taxonomy'        =>  $taxonomy,
            'name'            =>  'business',
            'orderby'         =>  'name',
            'selected'        =>  $term,
            'hierarchical'    =>  true,
            'depth'           =>  3,
            'show_count'      =>  true, // Show # listings in parens
            'hide_empty'      =>  true, // Don't show businesses w/o listings
        ));
    }
}
add_filter('parse_query','convert_business_id_to_taxonomy_term_in_query');
function convert_business_id_to_taxonomy_term_in_query($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    $qv =& $query->query_vars;
    if ($pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($qv['business']) && is_numeric($qv['business'])) {
        $term = get_term_by('id',$qv['business'],'business');
        $qv['business'] = ($term ? $term->slug : '');
    }
}
```