# Wordpress - Admin Manage Posts - Multiple Filters by Parent Category

Tags: posts, categories

Lets say I have the following Categories in Wordpress:

Product Category - Cat A - Cat B - Cat C

Service Type - Service A - Service B - Service C

On the Manage Posts page on the Admin side, I want to have 2 drop down filters for both Product Category, and Service Type, so I can filter by both on the backend.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe this is not an exact duplicate *(but I'll flag as such)*, because you're asking about `Posts` and the other about `Custom Post Types`, but the answer provided by Stephen Harris is built to filter `Posts`. Check his answer and adapt the taxonomy to your own. You will have to duplicate some blocks of code to make it work with 2 Custom Taxonomies. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/43007/12615

Comment: But I'm not looking to do with custom taxonomies.  Im just looking to do this with the standard Category in Wordpress.  I just want multiple <select> statements based off of each Parent Category.  So in the above, I want a <select> for Product Category, and a <select> for Service Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's quite a huge task to split the default taxonomy in two dropdowns. Maybe some wizard stumbles upon your question and enlighten us...

The biggest problem I see is the split itself, because you can modify the query `&cat=1` to `&cat=1,25` so as to list two categories (by their id's).

What I suggest is creating a custom taxonomy for dealing with either Products or Services. And leave the other in the default categories.
And then apply the [solution I linked](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/43007/12615) in the comments to the question.

This way is easy to have two dropdowns and do the custom filtering you're looking for.
Just tested and it works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, yeah I had done that.  Just wanted to make sure there wasn't a way to do it all as 'Categories'