# Filter Custom Post Type in Admin

Tags: wp-admin

I have a custom post type that has custom meta that I want to be able to filter on the Admin page. Much like the "All | Published | Drafts | and Trash"  links located above the post list. I can't seem to find a hook to hook into. Does one exist?

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/578/adding-a-taxonomy-filter-to-admin-list-for-a-custom-post-type) isn't exactly what I am asking. I would prefer not to have the filter dropdown, but instead a link like …

```
All | Published | Drafts | Trash
```

… across the top of the editor.

Comment: check the first question in the related column over there ->

Comment: I have seen this, but what I was asking is can you add a link to the list similar to the "All|Published|Drafts|Trash" links. My client finds the drop down a bit confusing, and would prefer a simple click a link setup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like in [Adding a Taxonomy Filter to Admin List for a Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/578/12615) the filter `parse_query` could be used, but here I'm using `posts_where`.

---

The row `All | Published | ...` is controlled by `views_edit-{$post_type}` and the `$views` array contains each item that's a simple anchor tag.

First, we insert a couple of links - a separator and a Meta filter:

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-portfolio', 'meta_views_wpse_94630', 10, 1 );

function meta_views_wpse_94630( $views ) 
{
    $views['separator'] = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    $views['metakey'] = '<a href="edit.php?meta_data=allorany&post_type=portfolio">Meta Key</a>';
    return $views;
}
```

The link contains `meta_data=allorany` (the custom field name), which will be used to filter by meta key.

[image]

---

And then, filter when needed:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'load_custom_filter_wpse_94630' );

function load_custom_filter_wpse_94630()
{
    global $typenow;

    // Adjust the Post Type
    if( 'portfolio' != $typenow )
        return;

    add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'posts_where_wpse_94630' );
}

function posts_where_wpse_94630( $where ) 
{
    global $wpdb;       
    if ( isset( $_GET[ 'meta_data' ] ) && !empty( $_GET[ 'meta_data' ] ) ) 
    {
        $meta = esc_sql( $_GET['meta_data'] );
        $where .= " AND ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='$meta' )";
    }
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: +1, this is slick. Though I do feel that somebody having "clients" ought to be able to modify Mike Schinkel's answer in the near-duplicate to their needs...

Comment: Thanks for this answer it was incredibly helpful. For whatever reason I missed the views_edit-{$post_type} and $views thing.

@Johannes Thank you for your piety, I will be sure to point all my clients in your direction in the future.

Comment: While probably still true, that might have been a tid bit of a snooty remark @micahmills, I'll give you that.

Comment: Had all kinds of problems with this that were hard to diagnose. I think because the second filter never gets removed, and so gets applied to all further queries, for any post type. See additional answer add with alternate solution

Comment: @mozboz, thanks for pointing that out. I did a search for `posts_where` and `remove_filter` here on WPSE and it yelds many results, certainly I'm missing removing the filter somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

With credit to @brasofilo for his answer, it gave me *all* kinds of problems for a reason I couldn't quite diagnose. I think the posts_where filter that gets added needs to be removed otherwise it will run for all future queries in the page and make a mess of anything that then tries to query a different post_type as the second filter will still be active.

Here's a solution that doesn't require hacking the SQL manually, but works on the Query object instead. Assuming using the method of adding URL params as in the other answer here with url param name cpt_filter

```
function filter_cpt($query) {

    global $pagenow;

    $cpt = "your_custom_type_name";
    $cpt_key = "some_key_to_filter_on";
    $cpt_value = "some_value_to_filter_for";

    if (is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' &&
        isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type']==$cpt &&
        isset($_GET['cpt_filter'])  && $_GET['cpt_filter'] != 'None' &&
        $query->query['post_type'] == $cpt)  {
      
          $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = $cpt_key;
          $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $cpt_value;
      }
    }

}

add_filter( 'parse_query', 'filter_cpt' );
```

No problems here with adding/removing filters, and flexibility with setting the meta key and value to whatever works.