# How to redirect from wp-admin/edit.php to a frontend page for specific custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I'm building a very tiny web app based on Wordpress.

For this, I have created a custom post type for the items users will be able to manage in the app.

I have created a very pretty, optimized overview page as a frontend page. However, to save development time, editing each item still takes place in the backend.

Some operations in the backend - namely, deleting an item - take the user to the items overview page in the *backend* (`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=my_item_post_type`) rather than my pretty frontend page.

I would like to prevent this, so that when the user is taken to `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=my_item_post_type` they will be redirected to the pretty frontend page.

Is there a hook I can utilize for this?

Comment: Ah, this seems to have the solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9353/is-there-a-wordpress-hook-to-filter-the-edit-posts-view will post an answer once I've got it working.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this, put in `functions.php` works for me, based on [this question and answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9353/is-there-a-wordpress-hook-to-filter-the-edit-posts-view):

```
/* Send users away from wp-admin/edit.php to page with ID 999
  for post type my_post_type */

add_filter( 'parse_query', 'filter_post_edit_screen' );

function filter_post_edit_screen($query) {
    global $pagenow;

    if (is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && $query->query["post_type"] == "my_post_type"){
     wp_redirect(get_permalink(999));
     exit;

    }
    return $query;
}
```

don't know whether it is clean to call `wp_redirect()` for this hook but don't see why not.