# Default to 'all' view on the 'edit-post' screen for authors

Tags: posts, filters

I try to figure out as the title mentions and I found this:

[How To Disable (or Remove) "All Posts, Published, and Trash" in Dashboard Posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224159/how-to-disable-or-remove-all-posts-published-and-trash-in-dashboard-posts)

And birgire's answer is spot on, but I need the "All" link to be default instead of the "Mine" and I just can't figure it out.

I also on another posttype want to default to "published"

Comment: Welcome, a quick working backwards in code of edit.php indicates that no easy solution. Perhaps filter the wpdb query with https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_parse_request/ ONLYwhen in edit posts (Code must check where it is, otherwise you'll impact other queries)  Based on what I see around line 261 https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_posts_list_table/get_views/, the 'views' at the top will adjust based on the query.    This might help https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9353/is-there-a-wordpress-hook-to-filter-the-edit-posts-view

Answer (score 0):

Thank's anmari,
A tad over my level of php knowledge, but manage to sort it out looking at it in another way. Sorted with changing the "global $submenu" and the code:

```
/**
* Makes the "All" sorting and "publish" default on edit screen for custom post types
*/

function default_post_sorting(){
        global $submenu;

        // Administrator users don't need this, bail out
        if( current_user_can('add_users') )
        return;

        //'publish' default
        $submenu['edit.php?post_type=my_post_type'][5][2] = 'edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=my_post_type';

        //'All' default
        $submenu['edit.php?post_type=my_post_type'][5][2] = 'edit.php?post_type=my_post_type&all_posts=1';

            }

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'default_post_sorting');
```

Just change "my_post_type" to your posttype.