# Custom post admin filtering by post meta (the date)

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, date-time, columns

I've created a custom post type for events that uses a custom field to retrieve the date for the event. It works ok and I'm able to filter the displayed results using `meta_compare` to compare the date value to the current date.

So far so good. I can also filter the admin end to display either future or past events (or both, by removing the `meta compare`) via a `pre get posts` filter.

What I want to do is to create an admin page that will display the past events. I've created the page (and menu item) with the following code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_concerts_page');
function add_concerts_page() {
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=concerts', 'Concerts Archive', 'Concerts Archive', 'manage_options', 'concerts-archive', 'my_archive_function' );
}

function my_archive_function() {}
```

But I don't know how to write the function!! I can write a regular loop and filter the results, as I would do on the front-end, but all I need to do is to show the same information as the normal admin page, but showing events that have since passed.

This is how I filter the custom posts edit screen to show only future events:

```
function concerts_pre_get_posts($query) {
  if (is_admin()) {
    if (isset($query->query_vars['post_type'])) {
      if ($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'concerts') {
          $query->set('meta_key', 'date_value');
          $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
          $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    $query->set('meta_compare', '>=');
          $query->set('meta_value', time());

      }
    }
  }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts' , 'concerts_pre_get_posts');
```

I don't really need to create a separate archive page for past events, just a link to toggle the query from past to future events on this page would be groovy, but I haven't a clue how to go about doing this!

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just found the following article that shows how to add a custom query select list to any post type

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-to-sort-the-admin-area-of-a-wordpress-custom-post-type-by-a-custom-field/159#159

Just have to change the query to filter results by comparing the timestamp to the current time and display either past or future events accordingly. Any good soul care to help me out?!

Answer (score 2):

You need to be storing your dates in some sortable format such as YYYY-MM-DD, or as a unix timestamp, otherwise you can't do this just with a query. Once it's in the format YYYY-MM-DD this should work. try this:

```
function concerts_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( isset( $query->query_vars[ 'post_type' ] ) && $query->query_vars[ 'post_type' ] == 'concerts' ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key' => 'date_value',
                'value' => date( "Y-m-d" ),
                'compare' => '<=',
                'type' => 'DATE'
            )
        ) );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'concerts_pre_get_posts' );
```