# Adding markup to column text in "Edit Pages" admin page

Tags: admin, hooks

I was wondering if there is a way to hook into the column titles in the "All Posts" admin page  to modify them. For instance, I would like to change "Post" to "`<strong>Headline</strong>`". Are there any hooks that would let be do this without modifying the WordPress core code?

I have found some information about adding columns and modifying custom post type columns, but I could not find any information on modifying the columns that are standard in the "All Posts" screen.

Comment: You're not going to get a lot of help writing custom code for a version of WordPress that was [published over 3 years ago](http://wordpress.org/about/roadmap/) (2.8 was released June 2009). Instead, I'd look to removing the roadblocks that are preventing an upgrade ...

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible since I am working for a small division of a large organization that manages dozens of sites on a single old WordpressMU install. I am editing the question to make it more broadly applicable, and I have found an answer that I could post if this thread is re-opened.

Comment: I'll re-open so you can post your solution ... generally, though questions about specific WP versions that are that old will be closed as Too Localized. You should really put some pressure on the organization to update; there have been loads of **security** and speed improvements in the past 3 years ...

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it! I have talked the division that I am working for to move to a stand-alone WordPress site, primarily for security reasons, but I doubt I'll be able to put too much pressure on the parent company.

Comment: Search for [`+sort +column`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%2bcolumn%20%2bsort), order by _newest_ and start at the last page. Some of our [old answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/45/73) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I found that there is a filter, [manage_posts_columns](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_posts_columns) (and a related [manage_pages_columns](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_pages_columns)), that lets you modify the column headers on the "All Posts" admin screen. Using this filter is pretty simple, as the filtering function takes in an associative array with the short name of the column as a key and the heading as the value. You just need to return a modified version of the array, and you're set:

```
function all_posts_modify_column($columns) {
    $columns['title'] = '<strong>Headline</strong>';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'all_posts_modify_column');
```