# wp-admin: Sort users by surname

Tags: admin, users, sort, table

[image]

Is it possible to alter this table in the backend so I can sort users by **Name** and **Surname**?

I have dozens of users on my multisite that need to be sorted by Surname.
Can anyone help me out here?

Kind Regards,
Matt

Comment: Have a look at this question: [How to change order of posts in admin?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66455/how-to-change-order-of-posts-in-admin)

Comment: You can achieve this easily with CodePress Admin Columns plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/

Just add surname to columns via admin columns settings page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these filters:

```
add_filter( 'request', 'users_orderby_column' );
function users_orderby_column( $vars ) {
    // Your code goes here
}
```