# wp-admin/users.php Add a column with last name

Tags: users, admin

How can I add an additional column containing the last name of the user in wp-admin/users.php?
It also should be sortable.

There is a similar question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/203478/181889 but I don't know how to work with the filter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 Steps

1. [Add custom column](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_users_columns)
2. [Fill data in custom column](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_users_custom_column/)
3. [Make the column sortable](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_this-screen-id_sortable_columns/)

```
//Add custom column
function my_custom_wp_filter_add_user_lastname_column($columns) {
    $columns['user_lastname'] = 'Last Name';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'my_custom_wp_filter_add_user_lastname_column');

//Fill in value in custom column
function my_custom_wp_filter_add_user_lastname_column_value( $column_output, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    if ( 'user_lastname' == $column_name ) {
        return $user->last_name;
    }
    return $column_output;
}
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column', 'my_custom_wp_filter_add_user_lastname_column_value', 10, 3);


//Make the column sortable
function my_custom_wp_filter_make_user_lastname_column_sortable( $colums_to_sort ) {
    $colums_to_sort['user_lastname'] = 'last_name';
    return $colums_to_sort;
}
add_filter('manage_users_sortable_columns', 'my_custom_wp_filter_make_user_lastname_column_sortable', 10, 1);
```

Edit : Response to requirement of ability to sort by user's last name

Wordpress does not allow users to be sorted by last_name by default.
See 'orderby' section in [WP_User_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working! :) However there seems to be an issue with the correct order. [link](https://i.imgur.com/H8rlKUZ.jpg)

Comment: Wordpress stores user last_name in usermeta table hence it does not allow "ordeby" with last_name straightforward. 
I tried various combinations using orderby=meta_value, but didn't get it to work.

Comment: I didn't expect that, damn. But thanks a lot for trying! :)