# How to add a filter based on custom field to admin user list

Tags: admin, filters, users

I have added a column to the user list using two wordpress hooks: manage_users_columns and manage_users_custom_column. That's working fine. Now I would like to filter the user list based on a custom user meta key. How can I add a custom filter to the admin user list? WP provides filters based on roles. Can I hook into them somehow?

Comment: This question may help you : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/578/adding-a-taxonomy-filter-to-admin-list-for-a-custom-post-type

Comment: This one too: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-to-sort-the-admin-area-of-a-wordpress-custom-post-type-by-a-custom-field/159#159